# jQuery .load method not working for asynchronously loading into div images

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, load

I am attempting to load images from my "img" folder into div #scrollerContent but I am unable to get it to work properly.

```
//Variables References
        var sections = $(".nav a"),
            pageBody = $("#scrollerContent"),
            next = $('.next'),
            prev = $('.prev'),
            img = $('img');

        //Manage loading of pages
        sections.on('click', function(){
            pageBody.load("img/" + this.id + ".jpg");
            sections.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a similar problem the following code worked for me.

```
//Variables References
    var sections = $(".nav a"),
        next = $('.next'),
        prev = $('.prev'),
        img = $('img'),
        largeImg = $('img.large');

    //Manage loading of pages
    sections.on('click', function(){
        largeImg.attr('src',"img/" + this.id + ".jpg"); 
        sections.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

at server, given

html,

i.e., at `/img/images.html`

```
<img id="image1" src="/img/path/to/image" />
```

at `document`,

```
<a href="#" class="image1">click</a>
```

js

```
    var sections = $(".nav a"),
        pageBody = $("#scrollerContent"),
        next = $('.next'),
        prev = $('.prev'),
        img = $('img');

    //Manage loading of pages
    sections.on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      pageBody.load("/img/images.html #" + $(e.target).attr("class"));
        sections.removeClass('selected');
        // is `$(this)` here intended for `<img>` , or `sections` ?
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/t1gkq3qc/